# Реализация паттерна Builder v4

Tags: java, шаблоны-проектирования, инспекция-кода

Реализация паттерна Builder (четвертая часть) + Junit тесты. Ссылки на предыдущие реализации Builder-a: **Часть 1** http://clck.ru/8pke3  **Часть 2** http://clck.ru/8pkeF   **Часть 3** http://clck.ru/8pknj

**1) Абстрактный класс BaseCarBuilder.**

```
public abstract class BaseCarBuilder {

    public abstract void buildBody();

    public abstract void buildColor();
}
```

**2) Класс Car.**

```
public class Car {

    public enum Color {RED, BLACK, WHITE}

    public enum Body {SEDAN, CABRIOLET, LIMOUSINE}

    private Body body;
    private Color color;
    private String name;

    public Car(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Body getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    public void setBody(Body body) {
        this.body = body;
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Car{" +
                "body=" + body +
                ", color=" + color +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**3) Класс CarBuilderDirector.**

```
public class CarBuilderDirector {

    private final BaseCarBuilder baseCarBuilder;

    public CarBuilderDirector(BaseCarBuilder baseCarBuilder) {
        this.baseCarBuilder = baseCarBuilder;
    }

    public void construct() {

        baseCarBuilder.buildBody();
        baseCarBuilder.buildColor();
    }
}
```

**4) Класс VolvoBuilder который наследуется от BaseCarBuilder.**

```
public class VolvoBuilder extends BaseCarBuilder {

    private Car car;

    public VolvoBuilder() {

        car = new Car("Volvo");
        defaultVolvoBuilder();
    }

    public Car getCar() {
        return car;
    }

    @Override
    public void buildBody() {

        car.setBody(Car.Body.LIMOUSINE);
    }

    @Override
    public void buildColor() {

        car.setColor(Car.Color.BLACK);
    }

    private void defaultVolvoBuilder() {

        car.setColor(Car.Color.WHITE);
        car.setBody(Car.Body.SEDAN);
    }    
}
```

**5) Класс Client**

```
public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

       CarBuilderDirector director = null;   
       VolvoBuilder volvoBuilder = new VolvoBuilder();
       director = new CarBuilderDirector(volvoBuilder);
       director.construct();
       System.err.println(volvoBuilder.getCar().toString());

    }
}
```

**Теперь реализация Junit тестов. Нужно было реализовать следующие тесты. Это мои вторые Junit тесты.**

[image]

**Тест № 1**

```
public class CarTest {

    @Test
    public void testWhiteSedanCarToString() {

        Car car = new Car("My Car");
        car.setColor(Car.Color.WHITE);
        car.setBody(Car.Body.SEDAN);

        final String actual = car.toString();
        final String expected = "Car{body=SEDAN, color=WHITE, name='My Car'}";

        assertEquals(expected, actual);
    }
}
```

**Тест № 2 и 4**

```
public class VolvoBuilderTest {

    // тест № 2
    @Test
    public void testCarBlackLimousine() {

        VolvoBuilder volvoBuilder = new VolvoBuilder();
        volvoBuilder.buildColor();
        volvoBuilder.buildBody();

        String actualBody = String.valueOf(volvoBuilder.getCar().getBody());
        String actualColor = String.valueOf(volvoBuilder.getCar().getColor());

        assertEquals("BLACK", actualColor);
        assertEquals("LIMOUSINE", actualBody);
    }

    // тест № 4
    @Test
    public void testWithoutBuildBodyAndWithoutBuildColor() {

        VolvoBuilder volvoBuilder = new VolvoBuilder();

        final String expectedCar = "Car{body=SEDAN, color=WHITE, name='Volvo'}";
        final String actualCar = volvoBuilder.getCar().toString();
        assertEquals(expectedCar, actualCar);
    }


    // тест № 4
    @Test
    public void testWithDirector_Construct() {

        VolvoBuilder volvoBuilder = new VolvoBuilder();

        CarBuilderDirector director = new CarBuilderDirector(volvoBuilder);
        director.construct();

        final String expectedCar = "Car{body=LIMOUSINE, color=BLACK, name='Volvo'}";
        final String actualCar = volvoBuilder.getCar().toString();
        assertEquals(expectedCar, actualCar);
    }

}
```

**Тест № 3**

```
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

    public class CarBuilderDirectorTest {

        @Test
        public void testDirectorConstruct() {

            BaseCarBuilder mockBaseCarBuilder = mock(BaseCarBuilder.class);
            CarBuilderDirector director = new CarBuilderDirector(mockBaseCarBuilder);
            director.construct();

            verify(mockBaseCarBuilder).buildColor();
            verify(mockBaseCarBuilder).buildBody();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Может уже хватит?

Comment: @Barmaley При всем уважении, @Иван_Белозеров0011 — это один тех людей на этом ресурсе, кто регулярно пишет и выкладывает код, а не занят выбором лучшей темы для Sublime и метанием между `Django` и `ASP.NET.` Что тут плохого-то? :)

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать а это гитхаб что-ли, код тут выкладывать? Пусть в своем первом вопросе обновляет, я уже предчувствую тут v5,v25 и так далее, зачем?

Comment: Я начинающий java программист, и мне очень важна и нужна Ваша помощь, замечания и поддержка в саморазвитии. Кому интересно - пусть читает и смотрит мои вопросы и реализации. "Котик_хочет_кушать" большое Вам спасибо за помощь и поддержку.

Comment: жду 5 пятый эпизод: "Билдер наносит ответный удар". Если честно немного мысль потерял, а что нужно то?)
что касательно кода:  VolvoBuilder volvoBuilder = new VolvoBuilder(); я бы заменил, на BaseCarBuilder volvoBuilder  = new VolvoBuilder();
не очень понятно зачем отложенная инициализация: CarBuilderDirector director = null; И вывод System.err.println(volvoBuilder.getCar().toString()); достаточно System.err.println(volvoBuilder.getCar()); Хотя так и не понимаю, чем Вам этот паттерн понадобился. Не очень понятны заранее установленные поля, смысл абстракции теряется...хотя я так и не понял смыс

Comment: @Иван_Белозеров0011 Я пропустил пилотные серии и смотреть их не особо хочется. В чем заключается ваш вопрос?

Comment: @a_gura хочет правильно паттерн реализовать, ну тут еще юнит тесты, но древнее зло не дремлет и всячески пытается помешать...хм..чет я все смотрю, мы с Вами по одним и тем же вопросам ходим)

Comment: @JEcho Желание - это не вопрос. В общем закрываю с формулировкой "Вопрос не по теме". Если я не прав, модераторы переоткроют.

Comment: Лучше бы вот [это,](http://goo.gl/tJWT7D) [это,](http://goo.gl/rJMzhM) [это,](http://goo.gl/4wFbjQ) [это,](http://goo.gl/xDmRbm) [это,](http://goo.gl/OMLbLF) [это](http://goo.gl/dnkPKK) и [это](http://goo.gl/BmM7tJ) закрыли, честное слово.

Comment: имхо, в исследования это надо. и реализовать сразу несколько паттернов (со временем).  
имхо2. тоже не понял зачем тут именно билдер.  
имхо3. сами по себе классы чем бы они не занимались и какие бы тесты не проходили, должны что-то делать, выполнять какую-то полезную функцию. кроме toString ничего полезного здесь нету.  

ЗЫ а учиться надо, да.

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать Эти топики мне, например, не интересны. Закрывайте, у вас же есть права. А вот эта серия уже порядком надоела. Да и не в формате форума она, по моему мнению. Я не понимаю, в чем проблема автора. Хочет, чтобы мы провели ревью кода? Так может отдельный форум под это завести.

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать темы закрыть могут многие (в т.ч. и вы). Я, как модератор, обычно действую только по тревоге. Тема @Иван_Белозеров0011 порядком уже поднадоела - нет она не нарушает правила форума, но как бы, я лично слегка **bored**. Минусуя его тему, я просто хотел дать хинт автору темы, что кое-кому это не нравится - как простой пользователь, я кажется имею на это право. Своим правом модератора я не злоупотреблял.

Comment: @Barmaley Без репрессий нет порядка ;) Ну в самом деле, правила может и не нарушает, но и полезной нагрузки не дает.

Comment: флудеры))...ИМХО: не очень понятно зачем все-то...кпд таких вопросов близко к нулю...ну ок реализуем в итоге это паттерн...и что? шампанское - хлопушки, поздравление президента?)...хабр полон статей о реализации паттернов. Учится нужно не на сферических паттернах в вакууме, а на решении конкретных задач, тогда и смысл всего этого откроется.
ЗЫ: не трогать таску про вывод из массива - в ней есть философия!))))

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что это древний code review запрос без контекста